# Storyboard could not be opened

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I am an amateur iOS developer running Xcode 5 and MacOS X 10.8.5, and I am making a universal app. I was working on my iPad storyboard when suddenly, a message popped up saying

> XXXX.storyboard" could not be opened. Could not determine the type of data.

When I tried to open it, it instead showed me the XML source code, as shown here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4510" systemVersion="12F37" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="QOo-HH-feM">
<dependencies>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3742"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="F6O-Ql-rEX">
        <objects>
            <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ViewController" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="QOo-HH-feM" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Pid-s8-44Q"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="sia-TJ-spg"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="2Vh-FD-gHS">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="1024"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JTc-0I-zmE">
                            <rect key="frame" x="-44" y="-20" width="828" height="1044"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <state key="normal" backgroundImage="6886658738_d647040ce5_o.png">
                                <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="keyboardKiller:" destination="QOo-HH-feM" eventType="touchUpInside" id="Ptv-XD-OwH"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9iy-2x-jn5">
                            <rect key="frame" x="251" y="589" width="256" height="86"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="86" id="Zuv-eF-8mI"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="256" id="l2b-Cj-XPD"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <state key="normal" title="Begin Hack" backgroundImage="Unknown.png">
                                <color key="titleColor" red="0.37254902719999999" green="0.99607849120000003" blue="0.0078431377190000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                                <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>
                            <state key="highlighted">
                                <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="hackStarter:" destination="QOo-HH-feM" eventType="touchUpInside" id="eqd-0q-t1S"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" scrollEnabled="NO" showsHorizontalScrollIndicator="NO" editable="NO" text="Phone " selectable="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="zZ7-b2-s9Z">
                            <rect key="frame" x="101" y="30" width="457" height="128"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="130"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" scrollEnabled="NO" showsHorizontalScrollIndicator="NO" editable="NO" text="Hack" selectable="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Jrq-y3-jiw">
                            <rect key="frame" x="109" y="187" width="457" height="128"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="130"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" image="Phone.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9YA-0f-5Hn">
                            <rect key="frame" x="478" y="66" width="328" height="261"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        </imageView>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="              Enter phone number here" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cBm-b5-sUV">
                            <rect key="frame" x="184" y="515" width="400" height="30"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="400" id="xVv-b9-c55"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="20"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="9iy-2x-jn5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2Vh-FD-gHS" secondAttribute="leading" constant="251" id="2dj-LZ-3tc"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="JTc-0I-zmE" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2Vh-FD-gHS" secondAttribute="leading" constant="-44" id="6nR-9o-oO1"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="JTc-0I-zmE" secondAttribute="bottom" id="8ws-Rb-DN7"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="JTc-0I-zmE" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2Vh-FD-gHS" secondAttribute="top" constant="-20" id="ITF-fw-n8Y"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="JTc-0I-zmE" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-16" id="OHN-hl-liO"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="9iy-2x-jn5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="cBm-b5-sUV" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="44" id="URZ-F6-T2k"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="cBm-b5-sUV" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="2Vh-FD-gHS" secondAttribute="centerX" id="dvN-od-bV1"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="cBm-b5-sUV" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="JTc-0I-zmE" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-509" id="gXO-U9-ej7"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="redBoulderRepublic" destination="cBm-b5-sUV" id="K6X-k6-iTf"/>
                    <segue destination="4Ms-NG-lSK" kind="modal" identifier="SegueOne" animates="NO" id="Npf-11-254"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="bQc-8Z-QvT" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="-106" y="-59"/>
    </scene>
    <!--View Controller - hackScreen-->
    <scene sceneID="whK-7q-MxG">
        <objects>
            <viewController storyboardIdentifier="hackScreen" title="hackScreen" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="4Ms-NG-lSK" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="IVQ-eO-0Yy"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="SsJ-De-fKh"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="UAs-ob-Fij">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="1024"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="acc-eB-kz2">
                            <rect key="frame" x="-116" y="0.0" width="1670" height="1194"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <state key="normal">
                                <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>
                        </button>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OKs-vg-G9J">
                            <rect key="frame" x="26" y="253" width="717" height="70"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4qS-Lv-5ch">
                            <rect key="frame" x="20" y="158" width="717" height="70"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ogk-SE-oK8">
                            <rect key="frame" x="26" y="358" width="717" height="70"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nuo-12-eso">
                            <rect key="frame" x="26" y="554" width="717" height="70"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="on3-kl-Z7B">
                            <rect key="frame" x="26" y="660" width="717" height="177"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OZG-KM-65h">
                            <rect key="frame" x="26" y="891" width="717" height="70"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RGY-oq-DYy">
                            <rect key="frame" x="26" y="457" width="717" height="70"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" text="Tap anywhere to proceed with hack" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aIu-90-MSl">
                            <rect key="frame" x="20" y="58" width="717" height="70"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.15686275059999999" green="1" blue="0.0039215688589999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="CourierNewPSMT" family="Courier New" pointSize="35"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ptx-VX-CXn">
                            <rect key="frame" x="-301" y="891" width="1083" height="70"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <state key="normal">
                                <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>
                        </button>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ffK-1i-P1M"        userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="881" y="-73"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
<resources>
    <image name="6886658738_d647040ce5_o.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <image name="Phone.png" width="512" height="512"/>
    <image name="Unknown.png" width="198" height="255"/>
</resources>
<simulatedMetricsContainer key="defaultSimulatedMetrics">
    <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="statusBar" statusBarStyle="lightContent"/>
    <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation"/>
    <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination"/>
</simulatedMetricsContainer>
</document>
```

Also keep in mind that the project is already in bundle resources, is already set to the initial iPad storyboard, and I have already set the XML version to 2.0 and 1.0 (changed it back since it doesn't fix the problem).

Comment: Is that the entire source code it's showing you?  It looks like you're missing a bunch of stuff at the top.

Comment: My comment is now outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Check your properties of the storyboard.
In the Identity and Type section you must have chosen XML. Change it to default!

Comment: It already says interface builder is default but it doesn't help.